# Display data in ListView from raw file

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to read data from a txt file located under res/raw/file.txt and display each line in a ListView. But when the app starts the ListView is empty.
This is defined before the onCreate:

```
private SimpleAdapter sa;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

This is the code:

```
     InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    try 
    {
        HashMap<String, String> item;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
            if (strings.length < 2) 
            {
                item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put("line1", strings[0].trim());
                item.put("line2", strings[1].trim());
                list.add(item);
            }
        }
        mTextView.setText("");

        sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.result,
                new String[] { "line1","line2" },
                new int[] {R.id.word, R.id.definition});

        mListView.setAdapter(sa);

        reader.close();


    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged and verified that your list isn't empty?

Comment: can you share the content of the text file, just 2-3 lines?

Comment: I'm new to Eclipse, so can you please tell me, where can I see list values?
Text inside the .txt file:
Car - a motor vehicle
Bike - a vehicle

Comment: I was referring to  res/raw/file.txt but any way, you can check the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks fine but there is a minor logical change  if (strings.length **<=** 2). and it works for me.

try

```
            if (strings.length <= 2) {
                item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put("line1", strings[0].trim());
                item.put("line2", strings[1].trim());
                list.add(item);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by defined before onCreate(). Defining before onCreate() does not mean that it will be called before onCreate(). You need to call the above code when the activity starts in onCreate().